# What is <_wmi_namespace: <COMObject <unknown>>?

Tags: python, wmi

I have been battling to make WMI from Python to run a .cmd file that in a remote machine.  I have an account as a standard user to run the .cmd file when the it only contains 1 line, `cmd.exe /c dir /b c:\ > c:\my_tmp.txt`.  But when I replaced the line to `file.exe -Execute -Action:CreateNew`, file.exe is not executed.

Here is the code I use to connect to a remote server, and print out the info sent through wmi.WMI()

```
conn = wmi.WMI(host, user = myUsername, password = myPassword)
print "===> conn object: ", conn
```

Here is the output after I ran the Python script in my local machine:

```
===> conn object:  <_wmi_namespace: <COMObject <unknown>>>
```

My questions:
1) What is <_wmi_namespace: >?
2)How do I verify the host and login credentials I sent to the remote server is correct?

Answer (score 0):

WMI utilises different namespaces, connecting to WMI involves connecting via a specific namespace (which will be the default if not specified), which allows different addons to run in different namespaces.

`COMObject <unknown>` indicates that Python doesn't know the details of the object that is being returned (in this case the WMI connector), this may be due to your runtime environment, or the COM library may not be fully registered/recognised.

You can verify that the connection was successfully established by accessing the properties of `conn`, e.g. `print c.Win32_OperatingSystem`.